# How to play .aac / .m4a files in cmus in 14.04 (trusty)?

Tags: 14.04, aac, m4a

I am unable to playback .m4a (aac) files in cmus.  They work in mplayer and totem. Anyone know a fix?

`$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS \n \l`

I already tried blowing away ~/.gstreamer*, updating cmus and cmus-plugin-ffmpeg...

Answer (score 2):

Currently the ffmpeg plugin is broken. To enable aac in .m4a or .mp4 libmp4v2 has to be enabled in the cmus build.

To that end you can build yourself adding `libmp4v2-dev` to the build deps.

Otherwise have latest 2.6  here in an almost stand-alone ppa, has another semi orphan in Aqualung. Libav support has been removed

https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/aqua-tests

As far as lavc support. The main issue is Libav has dropped swresample for avresample & cmus will not work well or at all with avresample. However FFmpeg still builds both.
So to that end a fully enabled cmus 2.6 with ffmpeg.so included is available here.

Please note that this ppa includes both Libav11 & FFmpeg 2.4.x & Will Not be Suitable for all. Read the page carefully before adding..

https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/testing6

Comment: Thanks for posting, but I gave up trying to get cmus working.  Whenever software I'm using is buggy or performs badly, I switch to something simpler.  I have resorted to just calling mplayer directly on the files themselves.  I pray that mplayer doesn't break; at that point I suppose I will have to call codec-specific programs.

Answer (score 1):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cmus/+bug/1311337

I found it reported in ubuntuforums.org.  Apparently ffmpeg broke backwards compatibility, it is fixed in newer cmus, but you have to build from source for now.

Update:  I tried building from source, no luck.  Probably related to this:

https://github.com/cmus/cmus/issues/139